# Baking Soft Boiled Eggs?

Tags: baking, eggs, cooking-time

For various reasons I have to bake yolks to the consistency of soft boiled eggs, what is a good temp and time to do this?

Comment: kinda intrigued about the various reasons why

Comment: Bake them separate, bake them all in larger bowl, bake them in some kind of cake or meatloaf?...

Comment: I just need the temperature and typical time to cook eggs to a soft boiled consistency for multiple recipes like meatloaf, deep-fried battered eggs etc. I don't see how what I'm using the eggs for matters I'm ONLY asking for a good temp and time for soft boiled yolks.

Answer (score 2):

A soft boiled eggs yolk is nothing more than raw egg yolk warmed up. You stop the cooking process right before it begins to congeal. The yolk itself is not considered "cooked". 
At 145° the yolk will still be completely liquid, jump it to 150° and the yolk starts to congeal.

> At 150° those egg yolks have gone from completely liquid to a soft, malleable texture that easily holds its shape.[Soft cooked eggs, Serious Eats](https://www.seriouseats.com/2013/10/sous-vide-101-all-about-eggs.html)

I'm really not sure of exactly what you're after, but those are the facts as far as temperature goes regarding egg yolks.

Answer (score 2):

Around 210 - 215 degrees Fahrenheit for 15 minutes depending on the egg and placement of the rack in the oven, but you'd need to experiment. You're essentially cooking from direct heat (boiling water) to ambient / convection heat (baking) - it's the same temperature, just a different dynamic. Baking will take longer.

Philippine [pancit (pansit) bihon](https://panlasangpinoy.com/2009/03/10/pancit-guisado/) is usually topped with a halved egg done just over soft-boiled, and when you make this for 100 + people, it's easier to just do the eggs in a convector oven.

I've never tried it in a standard home oven, but I can't imagine it being much different. So try:

1. Eggs at *room* temperature, and around 175 grams each
2. 5 eggs, spread out on the 4 corners and 1 in the center of the cookie sheet
3. Bake 12 - 15 minutes at around 215 if using convection, 20-ish minutes if not (I used convection when doing it).

Use a cake tester from the top of the egg to the center (the whites should definitely be hard by now, what remains is the center). Pull 'em out and ice bath 'em, or let them go a little longer.

Observe the doneness, this tells you the best spot in the oven to get close to the same results you would had you boiled them. In a convection oven it won't matter much, but conventional ovens have hot and cold spots.

I can't give an *exact* science for it, but I have done it, and that's the best advice I can give to gauge your own setup. Hope it helps :)